# Mysql Left join avoid repeating a table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a table repeating itself. I would like to `letter` show once and `letter_comments` in same table. Instead of repeating `letter` for each `letter_comments`

```
Letter
ID | TEXT |
1   My First Letter

Letter Comments
ID | LETTER_ID | TEXT |
3    1         Wow great one
4    1         This story is awesome
```

My Current query:

```
SELECT Json_object('id', l.id, 'text', l.text) AS letter,
       Json_object('text', c.text) AS letter_comments
FROM   letter_comments c
       LEFT JOIN letter l
              ON l.id = c.letter_id
```

Current result:

```
{letter: {id: 1, text: "My First Letter"}, letter_comments: {"Wow great one"}, letter: {id: 1, text: "My First Letter"}, letter_comments: {"This story is awesome"}}
```

Expected Result

```
letter: {id: 1, text: "My First Letter"}, letter_comments: {{"Wow great one"}, {"This story is awesome"}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `RIGHT JOIN`?

Comment: I've already tried it still repeat the `letter` for each `letter_comments`

Comment: My comment is not related to the repetition.

Comment: If you want letters that have no comments, you need to use `RIGHT JOIN` or change the order of the tables in the join. It's `parent_table LEFT JOIN child_table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to combine all the objects for the same letter in an array.

Also, you have the tables in the wrong order for `LEFT JOIN`. In a `LEFT JOIN` the parent table comes first, followed by the child table.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', l.id, 'text', l.text',
                    'letter_comments', JSON_ARRAYAGG(c.text)) AS letter
FROM letter AS l
LEFT JOIN letter_comments AS c ON l.id = c.letter_id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Comment: Cheers Man works like a charm, thanks for the explanation aswell!